# Why does JSON add slashes

Tags: java, mysql, json, servlets

I create a Json from a SQL query like this :

```
while(result.next())
   items.add("sourcename"+"\""+":"+"\""+result.getString("name"));
```

I retrieve it this way, and change it into a JSONObject :

```
SqlConnector sqlConnector = new SqlConnector(); 
    ArrayList<String> items = sqlConnector.getSourceType(sqlConnector.getId("users", "username", username)); 
    JSONObject toSendBack = new JSONObject(); 
    JSONArray dataArray = new JSONArray(items);
    toSendBack.put("data", dataArray); 
    toSendBack.put("success", true); 
    response.getWriter().print(toSendBack.toString());
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
```

I encouter some issue at :

```
toSendBack.put("data", dataArray);
```

And my received JSON is like that :

```
{"data":["sourcename\":\"Polo","sourcename\":\"BMW"],"success":true}
```

Why ? 
How can i remove these slashes ?

Comment: Use Google Gson library.

Comment: I did something like that :
Gson gson = new Gson();  
  JSONObject toSendBack = new JSONObject(); 
  JSONArray dataArray = new JSONArray(items); 
  String test = gson.toJson(dataArray);

  toSendBack.put("data", test); 
  toSendBack.put("success", true);
But not good ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your manual creation of the JSON line is incorrect.  I suspect it should be:

```
items.add("\"sourcename\":\""+result.getString("name")+"\"");
```

Although if "name" has double quotes in it things will go wrong.  Your best bet is to use a proper JSON library to handle all this for yourself.

Comment: Indeed, i create a method to do it by added some stuff to the JSONObject. (and not to the string). Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Don't remove the slashes, because that's how the JSON standard is defined for when you show the entire object as a string. If you extract the string from the JSONObject then the slashes are removed.

Edit: to find out the rules for how JSON changes string to it's own notation for "internal" use, see http://json.org/ for the string type.

Answer (score 0):

In case what you want to achieve is like this :  `sourcename:"Polo"`, the `slash` is used to add `""` to the string, try :

```
while(result.next())
   items.add("sourcename"+"\""+result.getString("name")+"\"");
```